# ng-include doesn't load template from script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, pug

I have an angular template script

```
script(type="text/ng-template" id="signalthread_template")
    .dp_wrapper
        .dp.ph(style='position:absolute;left:10px;top10px;width:40px;height:40px;')
            img.mw.inline_top(src='')
    .message(style='padding-left: 50px;')
        .n(style='margin-top: -3px;')
            span.bold Name here
            span , Title here
```

I have this ng-repeat

```
.message_wrapper.content_inner_content.p10(ng-repeat='message in [{type:"signalthread"}, {type:"jobthread"}, {type:"jobthread"}]' style='min-height:50px;')
    p {{message.type}}
    .include(ng-include src="'signalthread_template'")
```

The paragraph prints the correct thread template name. But the ng-include tries to make an http call for the template which does not exist.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: are you sure you have script template inside the `ng-app`/`bootstraped` element..otherwise those template wouldn't get compiled..

Comment: @PankajParkar, Yes I have this template inside ng-app

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), src expects angular expression evaluating to URL
You can save your template into a separate html file and then use file's name for the src